# Call login page only if the request comes from a specific URL

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.6 and I would like to secure my application in this way:

1. a single URL is always permitted (eg. `/student/login/<some code>`)
2. all the others URLs from the same category must be redirected (eg. `/student*` to `/student/loginPage`)

and so on for all the other categories, eg:

- `/category1*` > `/category1/loginPage`
- `/category2*` > `/category2/loginPage`

I tried a lot using the `SecurityFilterChain` methods but the only thing I've achieved is to permit one single URL and lock all the others (there is no distinction between categories).

```java
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/student/login/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/generalLogin")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
    .httpBasic();
```

I found no way to substitute `anyRequest()` with the one I want.

Comment: Why do you need more than one login page? In most cases this is not neccessary.

Comment: What do you mean by *3 different environments*. One instance of your application is only running in one enviroment. If you have 3 environments you should have three instances of your application.

Comment: 3 different sections: student, shop and admin. http://site.url/admin, http://site.url/student, http://site.url/shop, any subsection with his own login page

Comment: Why are you using section, these are role. You could handle it with one login and allow different access for different roles. There is no need for multiple logins.